# Eclipse: jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsimport error

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, jax-ws

I'm using the Maven Integration for WTP plugin in the Eclipse. When I try to import the Maven project which contains in the pom:

```
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
...
```

I got the error message:

```
No marketplace entries found to handle jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsimport in Eclipse.
Please see Help for more information.
```

I have googled and found similar situations without answers:

- http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/thread.jspa?threadID=4344&tstart=0
- http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home (at the end of the page)

Do you know how to fix the problem?

My environment is:

```
Eclipse:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Eclipse maven plugin:
Maven Integration for WTP
Version:   Maven Integration for WTP 0.15.3.20120830-0850
org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
```